# integrate a product of ratio and cos function

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I'm struggling with the following integral expression.

$$\int\limits_{d_\alpha}^Z \frac{s-d_\alpha}{\sqrt{1 + (s-d_\alpha)^2}} \cos\left(\frac{\frac{s}{d_\alpha} -h}{1-h} * \pi \right) ds$$

The aim is to use this primitive function in a control law.  Here $Z$ is the variable of the primitive function, while $d_\alpha$ and $h$ are constant.

Comment: What integral??

Comment: unfortunately I  joined a picture of the expression but apparentely it s not published, I am new here and it s my first time to ask a question, I ll try to edit this post are delete and repost it again

Comment: @abbes tahri Here are some suggestions for how to write a question so that it doesn't get closed (which this one still might).  In the meantime I have edited the post to display the integral under consideration.

Comment: @abbes tahri (1) It is standard practice to learn MathJax / LaTeX and typeset your math directly in the questions.  If you just link to images you will often find your questions closed (which still might happen).  (2) You haven't asked a question yet.  We understand that you're struggling, but what do you want help with? How are you hoping to use this primitive function in a control law? Can you provide some context for this primitive function / how you encountered it / what it means? (3) If this is a question about, say, control theory, you might consider including that in the tags.

Comment: I m really  thankful for your precious remarks, i gave up the direction implying that integration, i was intending to use it for a multi-agent flocking control  algorithm